# Spring MVC ResponseEntity and Cookies

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies

I am trying to add `Cookies` to `ResponseEntity` and I am not sure that [Adding cookies to header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642508/spring-inserting-cookies-in-a-rest-call-response) is the best practice.

1.When using `cookies` should I use a diffrent response like `HttpServletResponse`?

2.How can I add properties(`setMaxAge`, `setSecure`) in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the cookie in the httpresponse. In [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-cookie-example/) there is a good tutorial

Comment: I asked about ResponseEntity, I dont want to build the response all over again using HttpServletResponse.

Comment: I haven't try that. But maybe using: **HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Set-Cookie","cookie-name=cookievalue;max-age=*;expires=date; ...");** and then setting that in the EntityResponse might be a good idea then.