# Cookies passed with Spring ResponseEntity are not carried back in subsequent requests

Tags: javascript, java, spring, cookies, backbone.js

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Set-Cookie","accessToken="+accessToken);
return new ResponseEntity<String>(mapper.writeValueAsString(data), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I sent a cookie in ResponseEntity headers. Cookie `accessToken` is sent as Request Header (screenshot).

[image]

But when I looked at cookies under the chrome `Application` tab, I don't see `accessToken` cookie saved. And subsequent Ajax calls are not carrying this `accessToken` cookie. I am using backbone.js. Do I need explicitly tell ajax to carry cookies? I don't think so. Can someone tell me if this is the right way to set cookies?

Comment: Please check this similar question first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642508/spring-inserting-cookies-in-a-rest-call-response

Comment: Have you checked the cookie configuration of your chrome instance? It may not allow cookies from your API!