# How to send access token and refresh token in cookie and not in response in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have to pass the access token and refresh token in the cookie and not in body I am not able to find out a way out, can you please explain where I can set the cookie in response and remove the tokens from the response body?

Comment: did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40241038/175554

Comment: @özkanpakdil I have gone through the link, it tells to explicitly add a cookie to the response and add your parameters like "accessToken" in my case, while the problem statement is, the oauth2 tokens get generated in the response body when we use spring boot AuthorizationServerConfiguration and WebSecurityConfiguration, I need the tokens to be implicitly generated in the form of cookies not in the response body.

Comment: @Shubham parmar Did you find the answer?